# Determine the actual used size of an array

Tags: arrays, c

I have found the usual answer for determining the size on an array - 'variable = sizeof buffer/sizeof *buffer;'  or similar which gives the **declared** size

Other than passing a counter variable around when an array is 'filled', is there a way (a command or function - something similar to the above 1 liner) to find the used number of elements in a given array?

And I don't mean searching for an end of line character or implementing a circular buffer. I only expect between 5 and 25 Bytes in any given transaction.

Edit:- for omissions in original post (as requested)

Language C (via Atmel Studio)
8bit Bytes (non characters)
I don't know the meaning of 'strong-typed' and 'associative', but eventually it will be semi random bytes from a device and not fixed numbers like in a string
Fixed size declared array (ultimately volatile)

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. The size of an array depends on a large number of factors. An array of _what_? In which language? Is it a strong-typed array or an associative array? Is the size of the array pre-determined? Once you alloc memory for the array, it is all "used" by something. Do you wish to know how many positions of the array you actually modified? Keep track of them, there are at least two ways to do so.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include the important information. language C, 8bit Bytes (non characters). I don't know the meaning of 'strong-typed' and 'associative', but eventually it will be semi random bytes from a device and not fixed numbers like in a string.

Comment: please, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65217798/edit) your question and add the relevant tags and information.

Comment: Why not "passing a counter variable around" - is it schoolwork? Otherwise if there is unused value you can fill / initialize the array with 00/FF/etc, then scan until you find this value.

Comment: No it's not homework!! Just an honest genuine question because I do not know any better. The problem with searching for a predetermined value is, as stated - semi random, the bytes (Rx&Tx) values encompass the full 00 to FF range. The data is for a 1-Wire application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C standard generally does not provide any way for tracking or determining which or how many elements of an array are used.